# I keep getting the 'Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null at Image.img.onload error

Tags: javascript

```
<html>

<head>
  <title> OLL </title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type=text/javascript>
    //Loads Images
    //img.src = 'path/to/image.jpg';

    var img = new Image();
    var div = document.getElementById('foo');

    img.onload = function() {
      div.appendChild(img);
    };

    //img.src = 'path/to/image.jpg';
    img.src = 'bone.jpg';
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Whenever I open it up on chrome it doesn't show `bone.jpg`
`bone.jpg` is in the same folder as the html file and when I open up the console it shows

> Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null at Image.img.onload

I'm new to JavaScript so please make your response as simplified as possible.

Comment: Where is a `div` with the id `foo` in your markup?

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript MDN is a good resource to have on hand aside any usual free or paid online courses and books. See [**getElementById**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) for details which should also highlight that elements need to exists before queried.

Answer (score 2):

You need a div with the id `foo` in your markup to append to:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> OLL </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="foo"></div>

    <script type=text/javascript>
        var img = new Image(); 
        var div = document.getElementById('foo');
        img.onload = function() { div.appendChild(img); };
        img.src = 'bone.jpg';
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is great and all and I finally got it to work but is there anyway of having multiple pictures at the same time by using just one div tag?

Comment: @dope_asaurus If this answer solved your issue in the question please mark it as such. Any further issues or problems you are trying to solve should be asked in separate questions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `<div>` with the id `foo` to your HTML markup, otherwise your script can't find an element with such an id and return `null`, to which cannot be appended to:

```
[...]
<body>

<div id="foo"></div>

<script type=text/javascript>
[...]
```

In full code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title> OLL </title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="foo"></div>

    <script type=text/javascript>

    var img = new Image(); 
    var div = document.getElementById('foo');
    img.onload = function() {
        div.appendChild(img);
    };
    img.src = 'bone.jpg';


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```